# Getting Powershell variable value in batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want get value of an exported powershell variable in a batch script. Below are the sample scripts.

### sample.ps1

```
$myname="user1"
```

### sample.bat

```
@echo on
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell . "D:\sample.ps1"; (Get-Variable myname).value') DO SET VAL=%%i
echo %VAL%
pause
```

While executing sample.bat, I am always getting below error.

```
.value') was unexpected at this time.
```

But, if I execute like below in powershell I am able to get proper output.

```
. "D:\sample.ps1"; (Get-Variable myname).value
```

I want to know how to escape the parenthesis around Get-Variable command in batch script. Or would like to know any other way to get the value of exported powershell variable in batch script.

Comment: See if this post is what you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414300/calling-powershell-from-batch-and-retrieving-the-new-value-of-a-temporary-envir

Comment: @malexander Thank you for the link. But in this they are getting output of a powershell command say `get-date` and reading the value in batch script.

Comment: Also, tried to escape the closing parenthesis as below but still getting error. `FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell . "D:\sample.ps1"; (Get-Variable myname^).value') DO SET VAL=%%i echo %VAL%`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't BAT script recognize \ as an escape character?

Comment: @Vish According to my understanding \ will be used as escape character for regex patterns only. Please check [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Yes, correct - I ran your code and got the error irrespective of using the \ escape character. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have solved it!! I have to escape not only closing parenthesis and also the semi colon. I got a different error after adding escape character for closing parenthesis. `SET VAL=Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'myname'.` Working command...`FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell . "D:\sample.ps1"^; (Get-Variable myname^).value') DO SET VAL=%%i`

Comment: Interesting. I thought I almost got it - in commandline at least - but then it failed in a BAT script. One reason why I ported all my BAT scripts over to Powershell. Totally worth the effort!

Comment: How can we handle if multiple values returned/exported from a powershell and save it in variables in batch file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't test this without more information, but see if this helps:

```
@echo on
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('"powershell . "D:\sample.ps1"; (Get-Variable myname).value"') DO SET VAL=%%i
echo %VAL%
pause
```

Comment: Hi @foxidrive, can u let me know if we can handle multiple values returned/exported from a powershell and save it in multiple variables in a batch file

Answer (score 0):

Moved the answer added yesterday from comments section.

I have solved it!! I have to escape not only closing parenthesis and also the semi colon. I got a different error after adding escape character for closing parenthesis.

```
SET VAL=Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'myname'.
```

Working command is as follows...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell . "D:\sample.ps1"^; (Get-Variable myname^).value') DO SET VAL=%%i
```

@foxidrive Thank you for your answer and it also worked.