# How to put a single PowerShell output string into a cmd variable?

Tags: batch-file, powershell, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that outputs a single string value.  I have a cmd batch script that needs to execute the PowerShell script and place that single PowerShell output value into a variable in the batch script.  I'm finding all sorts of methods for exporting to a file or reading a file but that's not what I want.  Thanks!

(edit) Here's where I'm trying to use it (in response to posting the script):

```
@echo off
REM The next line puts the .ps1 output into the variable
REM and, obviously, this does not work
set pass_word=<C:\temp\PullPassword.ps1
tabcmd login -s "http://myserver.net" -u mylogon -p %pass_word%
```

( edit )
I saw the answer by the OP here **[Getting Powershell variable value in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367247/getting-powershell-variable-value-in-batch-scipt?rq=1)** and also looked at foxdrive's answer so I started playing with the FOR...DO statement.  I thought I was pretty good with cmd and couldn't figure out why what I had wasn't working:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell . "C:\temp\PullPassword.ps1"') do set val=%%a
echo  %a%
```

When I was looking at foxdrive's full answer in the other post it struck me: %a% was wrong, I needed %val%!  Oh, the shame!  The below works:

```
@echo off
set mypath=C:\temp\PullPassword.ps1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell . "C:\temp\PullPassword.ps1"') do set pass_word=%%a 
tabcmd login -s "http://myserver.net" -u mylogon -p %pass_word%
```

So I'll credit where it's due and mark foxdrive's answer correct, even though it was the other post that *clarified* my mistake.

Comment: Can you post your script, or at least enough of it to be able to demonstrate what it is you're trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may help: it expects that the powershell script outputs the text to STDOUT which is the normal place for it to appear.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell "script.ps1" ') do set "var=%%a"
```