# Setting a variable in batch using powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out.

this code

```
@echo off
powershell $Yesterday = (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd)
echo %Yesterday%

::neither one of these echo anything

@echo off
powershell Set-Variable -Name "Yesterday" -Value (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd)
echo %Yesterday%
```

should both return a response with yesterdays date (formatted as yyyMMdd), however, they do not. Using powershell, the following code does indeed work and return the correct response:

```
$Yesterday = (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd)
Write-Host $Yesterday

::Both of these work in powershell

Set-Variable -Name "Yesterday" -Value (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd)
Write-Host $Yesterday
```

however it does not work when used in batch. Any ideas why? I am trying to set the variable `%Yesterday%` in order to use it later in the script, but its not behaving itself as I expected. I'm sure its something simple, but I'm not seeing what it is right now.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414300/calling-powershell-from-batch-and-retrieving-the-new-value-of-a-temporary-envir)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This what you should use as code to set variable using `Powershell` and `Batch`

```
@echo off & color 0A
Title Setting a variable in batch using powershell
Set psCmd="get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd"
Call :RunPS %psCmd% YesterDay
Echo YesterDay was %YesterDay%
pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <Return value to be set as variable>
  for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set "%2=%%i"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner that will provide a var for yesterday's date in your batch script.  The second line cleans up the temp file used to create the variable.

```
powershell -command "((Get-date).AddDays(-1)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')">captureVar && set /p Yesterday=<captureVar
if exist captureVar del captureVar
```

Line 1 starts out by instructing the cmd line to use PowerShell for the commands contained within the double quotes.

```
powershell -command "the powershell command(s)"
```

As it's name implies, the first PowerShell cmdlet will perform a function to **Get-Date**.  Then, **AddDays** is used to change the date from the current value. A negative number will subtract and a positive number will add.

The default format looks like `Friday, December 20, 2019 6:18:29 PM`

To change the format, you must change the date into a string with format instructions

`.ToString('dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff K')`

The output of the PowerShell command is redirected into a file named captureVar. Another option would have been to have PowerShell write it to a file.

```
powershell -command "((Get-date).AddDays(-1)).ToString('yyyyMMdd') | set-content 'captureVar'" && set /p Today=<captureVar
```

I used && to make it a one liner. But you can set the var anytime after value has been written to the file.

```
set /p Today=<captureVar
```

The next line cleans up the temp file used to help create the var.

Comment: saving output to file is not a good idea for temporary items, and you need to delete it after using

Comment: @phuclv  you are absolutely correct.  I've added a line to clean up the temp file used to create the var.

Answer (score -3):

Defne the variable in batch, retrieve from Powershell

```
@echo off
%Yesterday% = powershell -command (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -format yyyyMMdd)
echo %Yesterday%
pause
```